# Converting complex object to dictionary<string,string>

Tags: c#, dictionary

I need to convert a dto object class like this :

```
 public class ComplexDto 
    {
        public ComplexDto()
        {
            ListIds = new List<ListIdsDto>();            
        }

        public string Propertie1 { get; set; }
        public string Propertie2 { get; set; }

        public IList<int> ListIds { get; set; }        
    }
```

to a `dictionary<string,string>`.

This is just some class example, this class will be used as json object like this:

```
     {"Propertie1":"ss","Propertie2":"","ListIds":[1,2,3]}
```

I need to pass this object to a FormUrlEncodedContent(dictionary) as dictionary of strings.

I have this :

```
     var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();            
     data[string.Empty] = ComplexDto.ToJson();
```

And I would like to transform the ComplexDto.ToJson() or the ComplexDto object to a Dictionary string, string.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: What is ListIdsDto? There is also only a single class, where is the collection that you want to use for the dictionary?

Comment: And what is supposed to be converted to what exactly?

Comment: How exactly do you wish the `ComplexDto` to look as a string?

Comment: Do you need to be able to convert back from the string representation to a ComplexDto instance?

Comment: I misread your question, I guess you want to return the properties of your dto as a dictionary of property.name property.value

Comment: The main question is how you want the IList<int> ListIds to _look_ as a string, ?comma seperated list of ints? 
Also I assume you may have lots of other types to consider.
One thought is that the string representation of complex-type value could be the The serialised XML or 'Inner' JSON http://json.org/example for the Value, but then why not just USE XML or JSON?
You need to consider and communicate how you would expect the value string to look,  but this sounds a lot like 'serialization with a dictionary wrapper'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a collection with some `ComplexDto` instances like:

```
List<ComplexDto> complexDtoList = ...;
```

and you expect that there are duplicate keys which would cause an exception(otherwise you could have used a dictionary in the first place).

You can use `Enumerable.GroupBy` to get unique keys. Then you have to decide what you want to do with the 1-n `Propertie2`-strings per group. One way is to use `String.Join` to concat all with a separator:

```
Dictionary<string, string> result = complexDtoList
    .GroupBy(dto => dto.Propertie1)
    .ToDictionary(
        p1Group => p1Group.Key,
        p1Group => string.Join(",", p1Group.Select(dto => dto.Propertie2)));
```

You could also build a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` and use `p1Group.Select(dto => dto.Propertie2).ToList()` as value.